# EditText Input Format

Tags: c#, xamarin

I would like to make a EditText field with format like this: 0000 AA.

Is it possible to make number keyboard appear at first 4 numbers then automatically make a space and then make normal keyboard appear?

How can I do that with C#?

Somebody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
EditText zipcode = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.zipcode);
zipcode.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber;
bool numberMode = true;
zipcode.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {
    if(zipcode.Text.Length == 4){
        if(numberMode){
            numberMode = false;
            zipcode.Text = zipcode.Text + " ";
            zipcode.SetSelection(zipcode.Text.Length);
        }
    }

    if(zipcode.Text.Length > 4){
        numberMode = false;
        zipcode.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassText;
    }

    if(zipcode.Text.Length <= 4){
        numberMode = true;
        zipcode.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber;
    }
};
```

Comment: Also take a look at: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/6914/#Comment_6914 which does something similar.